# Override syntax highlighting with color of hex code.

Tags: faces

From [EmacsWiki: Hex Colour](http://www.emacswiki.org/HexColour), it is explained how to get in-line syntax highlighting of hex code, and other formats of color. For instance with

```
(defvar hexcolour-keywords
  '(("#[abcdef[:digit:]]\\{6\\}"
      (0 (put-text-property (match-beginning 0)
                            (match-end 0)
                            'face (list :background 
                                        (match-string-no-properties 0)))))))
```

But when I try this with some emacs-lisp such as

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil
                    :weight 'bold :box '(:line-width 1 :color "#D8ABA7")
                    :foreground "#D8ABA7" :background "#FFE6E4")
```

the hex is not given the color face. If I try `M-x describe-face` on these, I find face is `org-block-background`. Is there a good way to override this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also achieve this using [`rainbow-mode`](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/rainbow-mode.html), which is part of ELPA.  Install it with `M-x package-install rainbow-mode` and activate it with `M-x rainbow-mode`.  It seems that the color changes don't occur until you edit the buffer.

Comment: "There is a good chance that someone already solved the problem, and made a package out of it". And an extra plus, package automagically inverts foreground to black or white for readability.